# column is not a column of the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to determine the evaluation and the final conformal predictions for my model with my data. But it gives me following error:

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maria/CP/scripts/Conformity_PredictionsV4.py", line 89, in <module>
    icp.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/maria/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 454, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

## Code Sample

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from nonconformist.cp import IcpRegressor
from nonconformist.base import RegressorAdapter
from nonconformist.nc import RegressorNc, AbsErrorErrFunc, RegressorNormalizer, NcFactory
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Load Environment and Models
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup training, calibration and test data
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
df = pd.read_csv ("prepared_data.csv")


# Initial split into train/test data
train = df.loc[df['split']== 'train']
valid = df.loc[df['split']== 'valid']

# Proper Validation Set (Split the Validation set into features and target)
X_valid = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_valid = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Create Training Set (Split the Training set into features and target)
X_train = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_train = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Split Training set into further training set and calibration set
X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size =0.2)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Train and calibrate underlying model
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
underlying_model = RegressorAdapter(DecisionTreeRegressor(min_samples_leaf=5))
print("Underlying model loaded")
model = RegressorAdapter(underlying_model)
nc = RegressorNc(model, AbsErrorErrFunc())

print("Nonconformity Function Applied")
icp = IcpRegressor(nc)  # Create an inductive conformal Regressor
print("ICP Regressor Created")

#Dataset Review
print('{} instances, {} features, {} classes'.format(y_train.size,
                                                   X_train.shape[1],
                                                   np.unique(y_train).size))

icp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

## Example Dataframe

```
new_host  split     sequence    expression
FALSE     train     AQVPYGVS    0.039267878
FALSE     train     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878
FALSE     train     STNLYGSGR   0.261456561
FALSE     valid     NLYGSGLVR   0.265188519
FALSE     valid     SLGPSNLYG   0.419680588
FALSE     valid     ATSLGTTNG   0.145710993
```

I've tried splitting the dataset in various ways but I am continuing to have trouble with this. In this case I want to split the data into train and test sets according to an observation's Data Split value. After which, I will split the train set into train and calibration in a second step. Where myfeatures, X_train and my target, y_train

Comment: Which line is the line 89 ?

Comment: @Hugolmn sorry for the lack of clarification, this is the last line where I'm trying to fit the model on the training data.

Comment: This line looks weird to me : model = RegressorAdapter(model). Is model defined somewhere ?

Comment: @Hugolmn sorry, I copied the wrong code, I've updated the post. This would actually be  `model = RegressorAdapter(underlying_model)`